# VBA - Multi wildcard filter using array values

Tags: excel, vba

Hello VBA Developers,

I am having a hard time solving a multi-wildcard filter for criteria(s) listed in an array. The code stops at "vTst = Doc_ID_Arr(i)", stating vTst = Empty. However, checking Doc_ID_Arr is not empty if you check the debugger.

```
Sub doc_id()
'Segment 1 ----
'Get the worksheet called "LOB Docs"
Dim sh_1 As Worksheet
Set sh_1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LOB Docs")

' Declare an array to hold all LOB Doc ID numbers
Dim Doc_ID_Arr As Variant
Dim Doc_ID_Value As String
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

With sh_1
lastrow_Header_Config = sh_1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Read LOB DOC ID's from Column Cell A2 to last value in Column A
ReDim Doc_ID_Arr(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh_1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow_Header_Config)) - 1) As Variant
j = 0
For i = 2 To lastrow_Header_Config
    Doc_ID_Value = sh_1.Range("A" & i).Value
    If Doc_ID_Value <> "" Then
    Doc_ID_Arr(j) = "*" & Doc_ID_Value & "*"
    j = j + 1
    End If
    Next
   End With
'  ' Debug.Print "Doc_ID_Value"
'    For i = LBound(Doc_ID_Arr) To UBound(Doc_ID_Arr)
'        Debug.Print Doc_ID_Arr(i)
'    Next i




'Segment 2 ----
   Dim sh_2 As Worksheet 'Data Sheet
   Dim sh_3 As Worksheet 'Output Sheet
   Set sh_2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GDL db") 'Data Sheet
   Set sh_3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Seed Template Output")

   Dim Dic As Object
   Dim eleData As Variant
   Dim eleCrit As Variant
   Dim ArrData As Variant
   Dim vTst As Variant

   Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   Dim x As Long

   For x = LBound(Doc_ID_Arr) To UBound(Doc_ID_Arr)
       vTst = Doc_ID_Arr(i)
   Next x

   With sh_2
   .AutoFilterMode = False
   ArrData = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
   For Each eleCrit In vTst
        For Each eleData In ArrData
            If eleData Like eleCrit Then _
            Dic(eleData) = vbNullString
        Next
   Next
    .Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Dic.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
   sh_2.UsedRange.Copy sh_3.Range("A1")
   End With


End Sub
```

I am trying to filter sh_2, Column A for each value(individual) or all values(en masse) that is placed in the Doc_ID_Arr created in Segment 1. The target is to place each filter output for each ID onto sh_3, without overwriting previous placed values/rows.

Comment: Note. Your indentation is off and is obscuring the logical flow of the code. Please see this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `i` within this loop:   `For x = LBound(Doc_ID_Arr) To UBound(Doc_ID_Arr)
       vTst = Doc_ID_Arr(i)
   Next x`. Why do you need a loop anyway?

Comment: Hello Ben, I am not sure if I need a loop to enter my criteria array values in to vTst. Since, my array holding the document ID’s are Variant, and VTst is a variant as well.

Comment: That is not how you populate an array. And `Doc_ID_Arr` is already an array, why are you trying to create a new one?

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for feedback on the initial code. This post has been solved by Tim Williams. much gratitude to Tim W.

Comment: Great! Then please accept Tim's answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your previously-posted sample workbook this works for me:

```
Sub document_link_extract()

    'Define data source
    Dim GDL_Data As Worksheet 'Datasheet holding Docs links
    Dim LOB_Doc As Worksheet 'Docs to filter for
    Dim Doc_Output_sh As Worksheet 'Seed Template - curated document list
    Dim Doc_ID_List() As String, v, rngIds As Range
    Dim arrVals, arrSearch, dict, rwV As Long, rwS As Long, srch

    Set GDL_Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'DataSheet
    Set LOB_Doc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Filter Criteria Sheet
    Set Output_sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") 'Output for' Look 1/2 - URL Check & PDF Extract

    Output_sht.UsedRange.Clear

    'get array of search terms
    With LOB_Doc
        arrSearch = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    'get array of data column values
    With GDL_Data
        arrVals = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'loop over each search term
    For rwS = 1 To UBound(arrSearch, 1)
        srch = "*" & arrSearch(rwS, 1) & "*" '<< search term with wildcards
        'loop over each value
        For rwV = 1 To UBound(arrVals, 1)
            v = arrVals(rwV, 1)
            'if value matches search term then add to dictionary
            If v Like srch Then dict(v) = True
        Next rwV
    Next rwS

    GDL_Data.AutoFilterMode = False 'if there is any filter, remove it

    'filter using the dictionary keys array
    GDL_Data.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, dict.keys, xlFilterValues
    GDL_Data.UsedRange.Copy Output_sht.Range("A1")

    GDL_Data.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim, Thank you so much, sir, this works perfectly!