# VBA Autofilter not filtering wildcard criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I wrote the following code to loop through data on another sheet, filter by multiple criteria, then copy that data to another sheet.  It works to an extent. It will not filter for all the values in the array because 2 of those values are wildcards. Looking for assistance on how to get the code to pickup all the array items which may or may not contain multiple wildcards.

```
Sub OriginalTestCode()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wbkDst As Workbook
    Dim my_filename As String
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    my_filename = wb1.Sheets("Template").Range("B10")
    
    Set wbkDst = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_filename) 'Claims Payable Analysis
    
    'setup array to load product lines
    Dim ProductLines As Variant, ProductRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim prodcol As Long, prodlrow As Long, matchprodcol As Long, x As Long, i As Long
    Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long
    
    prodcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Product", wbkDst.Sheets("Psoft Detail").Range("1:1"), 0) 'product column
    prodlrow = wb1.Sheets("lookups").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of product lines
    
    'convert acct detail to string
    wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("K:K").TextToColumns Destination:=wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("K:K"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
    wbkDst.Sheets("Psoft Detail").Range("I:I").TextToColumns Destination:=wbkDst.Sheets("Psoft Detail").Range("I:I"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
    'load products into array
    Set ProductRng = wb1.Sheets("lookups").Range("K2:K" & prodlrow) 'set range for product lines
    
    ReDim ProductLines(ProductRng.Cells.Count - 1)
    
    For Each cell In ProductRng.Cells 'load array with values
       ProductLines(x) = cell.Value
       x = x + 1
    Next cell
    
    With wbkDst.Sheets("Psoft Detail")
        'filter Psoft data by current month date
        Dim datecol As Long, fdom As Long, JEcol As Long, payRng As Variant, expRng As Variant, pay As Range, exp As Range
        Dim startrwpayments As Long, startrwexpense As Long, acctcol As String
        Dim paylrow As Long, explrow As Long
        
        datecol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date", .Range("1:1"), 0) 'date column
        JEcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("JE Header Descr", .Range("1:1"), 0) 'JE Header column
        fdom = DateValue("1-" & wb1.Sheets("Template").Range("B3") & "-" & wb1.Sheets("Template").Range("B5")) 'first day of month
        
        paylrow = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row 'claims payment last row
        payRng = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("N2:N" & paylrow)
        explrow = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row 'claims payment last row
        expRng = wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("P2:P" & explrow)
       
        For i = 0 To UBound(ProductLines) 'copy data to account detail tab
            .Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=datecol, Criteria1:=">=" & fdom, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & GetLastDayOfMonth(fdom) 'filter date column
            .Cells(1, prodcol).AutoFilter field:=prodcol, Criteria1:=ProductLines(i)
            If .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then  'check to make sure there are product line entries
                acctcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductLines(i), wb1.Sheets("Lookups").Range("K2:L" & prodlrow), 2, False)
                
                'filter and copy data to account detail column for claims payment IBNR
                    .Cells(1, JEcol).AutoFilter field:=JEcol, Criteria1:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(payRng), Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    
                    If Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
                        lrow = wbkDst.Sheets("Account Detail").Range(Cells(5, acctcol), Cells(Rows.Count)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
                        .Cells.Range("P2:Q" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                        wbkDst.Sheets("Account Detail").Range(acctcol & lrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If
            End If
            
            'reset autofilter for product & JE Header
            .ShowAllData
            
        Next i
        
    End With
    
    wb1.Sheets("Template").Range("C17") = "Verification Needed"
    MsgBox "Account Detail imported successfully", vbOKOnly
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I know the issue comes from the following line of code. It will allow me to correctly filter 2 of the non-wildcard items.

```
.Cells(1, JEcol).AutoFilter field:=JEcol, Criteria1:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(payRng), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Examples of payRng values that I would need the filters. These are the items loaded into the Array I created.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885988/vba-multi-wildcard-filter-using-array-values/58886715#58886715